# Studying the uniform convergence of $f_n(x) = \dfrac{1}{1+(nx-1)^2}$ on $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

As the question says, Im trying to see whether $(f_n)$ converges uniformly on $[0,1]$

Clearly, We observe that $\lim f_n = 0 $. Now, I see it is pointwise since if $\epsilon > 0$ one can choose $N > \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon} (x-1)}$ and so for all $N>n$ we have

$$ \dfrac{1}{1+ (nx-1)^2} < \dfrac{1}{(nx-1)^2} < \dfrac{1}{n^2 (x-1)^2} < \epsilon $$

Thus $f_n \to 0$ point wise. But, I am unable to verify whether it is uniform. Is my work correct?

Comment: Pointwise limit for x=0?

Comment: Convergence is not uniform because the pointwise limit is not continuous. (The limit is $\frac 1 2$ when $x=0$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f_n(x)$ converges pointwise to $f(x)$ on $S$ and $M_n=sup_{x \in S}|f_n(x)-f(x)|$, then $f_n(x)$ converges uniformly to $f(X)$ on S iff $M_n\to 0$, as $n\to\infty$.

Here $f_n(x)$ converges pointwise to  $0$. So, we need to find  $M_n=sup_{x \in S}|f_n(x)-0|=|f_n(x)|$. Now, at $x=0$, we have $M_n|_{x=0}=\frac{1}{2}$. Now, clearly as $M_n\nrightarrow0 $, as $n\to \infty$. Hence, the convergence is not uniform.

Comment: thanks! my proof for pointwise convergence is enough?

Comment: Yes. It seems correct.